# Spring Batch Tasklet with Task-Executor

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I got a weird issue about spring batch tasklet step with task-executor. The configuration is normal and simple, just a tasklet (no chunk-oriented) as below:

```
<batch:job id="MyJob" restartable="false">
        <batch:step id="MyJob.Step1">
            <batch:tasklet ref="someBean" task-executor="simpleAsyncTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="1"/>
        </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The **someBean** is an instance implementated **Tasklet** interface. The stange thing is when I launch the job, the **execute** method called twice:

```
@Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    // some logic and no exception

    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
}
```

**actually two threads are created** and executed the logic twice. And if I change task-executor to the normal 
`task-executor="syncTaskExecutor"` (org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor) , only one thread created and execute() invoked once.

Does anyone encountered this case and could give some idea? I really do not know "who" and "when" created two threads? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you specify an asynchronous `task-executor`, your tasklet will be  executed concurrently by multiple threads. The limit can be set using [throttle-limit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/xml/spring-batch-3.0.xsd#L668) which defaults to 4. In your case, two threads will execute the tasklet.

On the other hand, the [`SyncTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SyncTaskExecutor.html) will run the tasklet in the calling thread, which means only once since there are no other threads created.

Comment: Thanks mahmoud. so if I set throttle-limit to 1 which will run twice not once?
Also I noticed that I override doExecute(Runnable task) method in SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor, if execute task.run() will only one thread runing, but if Thread thread = new Thread(task); thread.start(); will get two threads run and executing the task twice. But I need create a new Thread to stop it at some stage, one workaroud is after thread.start(); I use countDownLauch.await(); then only one thread run, a little strange, but made it work for me. Thanks